# Visual studio Code not running Python 3

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

My computer:
MacBook Air M1
Running 11.6.3
Memory 8GB

Things I have tried:

1. Reinstalled Visual studio code
2. Use pyenv to install Python 3.10.2
3. pyenv install 3.10
4. pyenv global 3.10
5. Had brew reinstall pyenv 2.2.4
6. Also tried command python3.10 -V   just reverts back to python 2.7 right away.

Every time I open Visual studio code, to get python 3 to run I must run the two commands below.  Just wondering if there is a more permanent solution to the problem. Once I run the command, I have no problems, and can run python programs normally, but the next time I restart Visual studio code, the same issue comes back. Any solution would be helpful... many thanks!!

alias python="python3" # to use python3 rather than python2.7

alias idle="idle3" # to use python3 idle rather than 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Simply running the command python3.10 fixed the problem. I was just using python nameoffile.py to run a program.  Not aware that VSC was defaulting to Python 2.7 built into the Mac OS.

python3.10 nameoffile.py

Many Thanks everyone